# Delete extra Vim Latex menus

Tags: vim, latex

I've installed [vim latex](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download&title=Download) recently and this plugin causes a lot of additional menu items to appear in macvim:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<apple icon> File Edit Tools Syntax TeX-Suite TeX-Environments TeX-Elements
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

These are unnecessary to me and actually cause a problem since the new longer menu now hides other info on the top of my screen (such as the clock, battery life, etc).  Is there a way to get rid of these additional menu items (TeX-Suite, TeX-Environments, TeX-Elements)? It seems like the relevant file is in `.vim/ftplugin/latex-suite/texmenuconf.vim`.  I'd prefer to add something to my .vimrc, rather than edit files directly in the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `:unmenu` to remove menu items. Try `:help :unmenu` to get the details.